# jQuery insert/remove text at specific position in input field/textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to do similar thing as YouTube has when you are embeding a video and you want to get a code. You can click on checkboxes or select size and it dynamically changes the value of input field.

Does somebody have idea how to do it?

I managed to write a code that is replacing the width correctly, but I dont know how to make a code that would add `&scheme=XXX` at the end of the link or remove it if user selects no color scheme.

This is the code for width,I dont think its best one, but **works**:

```
$("#width").on("change keyup", function(){
    var width = $(this).val();
    if (width){
        $("#embed-text").val($("#embed-text").val().replace(/ (width\s*=\s*["'])[0-9]+(["'])/ig, ' width=\''+width+'\''));
    }
});
```

Here is textarea which I am trying to change and inputs I'm using for it:

**The ID is taken from PHP, in actual textarea that jQuery sees the `".$id."` is actual number**

```
<textarea class='clean' id='embed-text'><iframe src='http://my.url/embed/?r=".$id."' width='600' height='".$height."' frameborder='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe></textarea>

<div style='padding-right: 10px; display: inline-block;'>
    Color scheme: 
    <select id='schemes' class='clean'>
        <option value='-'>None</option>
        <option value='xxx'>Xxx</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style='padding-right: 10px; display: inline-block;'>
    Width: <input type='number' min='250' max='725' value='600' id='width' class='clean'>
</div>
```

When user does not select any scheme (or changes from XXX to None), I want link in textarea (iframes src) to be like this:

http://my.url/embed/?r=X

But when he selects any scheme, i would like it to look like this:

http://my.url/embed/?r=X&scheme=XXX

I actually have no idea how to do this. Tried googling for more than hour, but I don't know what the ID will be (to identify position where to add the string), thats PHP value and I cant pass it to external script file, so I tried to find if I can insert something at specific position (ie.: 15th character from start) with JS, but could not find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: The width you are trying to change is the iframe's width?

Comment: The width is ok, I posted a code there that works, but if somebody has an idea how to improve even on that, Im not against it. But what I need is to change the link thats in textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I separate some functions in order to keep the code clean check this I think that is what you were looking for [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cz4wcec/)

```
var generateUrl = function(id,colorScheme) {
    var baseUrl = "http://my.url/embed/?";
    var url = baseUrl.concat("r="+id);

    if (colorScheme != null && colorScheme != '')
        url = url.concat("&scheme="+colorScheme);

    return url;
};

var changeUrl = function(id, colorScheme) {
    var url = generateUrl(id, colorScheme);
    var srcPattern = "src='(.*?)'";
    var embedText = $("#embed-text").val();
    var newEmbedText = embedText.replace(new RegExp(srcPattern),"src='"+url+"'");
    $("#embed-text").val(newEmbedText);

};


var changeWidth = function(newWidth) {
    var widthPattern = "width='([0-9]*)'";
    var embedText = $("#embed-text").val();
    var newEmbedText = embedText.replace(new RegExp(widthPattern),"width='"+newWidth+"'");
    $("#embed-text").val(newEmbedText);
};

var getURLParameter = function(url,parameterName) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + parameterName + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(url)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
};

var getId = function() {
    var urlPattern = "src='(.*?)'";
    var embedText = $("#embed-text").val();
    var url = embedText.match(new RegExp(urlPattern))[1];
    var id = getURLParameter(url, 'r');
    return id;
};

$("#width").on("change keyup", function(){
    var width = $(this).val();
    var colorScheme = $(schemes).val();

    changeWidth(width);
    changeUrl(getId(),colorScheme);
});
```

And i removed the value '-' for the first option just leave it in blank.

Comment: In the url  you are forgetting, that I dont know the ID and cant hard code it to the script... Also, the last part should be different. #width is just for with. The scheme should have ``$("#schemes").change(function(){ do stuff });``

Comment: Where do you have the id? Maybe you can store it into an input hidden or something similar and take it out using **val()** function.

Comment: I dont really want to do it like that. I want to just change the value inside textarea without any hard coded values in script like baseUrl or ID.

Comment: Any way of doing it without need to have URL hardcoded in JS? I hate having to change same thing on XY different places. I think the getId function with small change to remove parameters would work. Ill be really thankfull if you can to id. Ps.: Why do you set functions as variables? You would call them the same way, so I dont see a difference.

Comment: Check the the response now, there is not hardcore url in that way. You can declare function in variables. It is simple the way i like to do it. You don't have to modify the code in order to make it work.

Comment: ``var baseUrl = "http://my.url/embed/?";`` ??? I think thats hardcoded url and not taken from textarea.

Comment: Ahh, that's right, sorry about that, you just have to make a function to extract the url.

Comment: Ok I think I can come up with something on my own. But one more question. I will be changing my URLs to look cleaner, so ``http://my.url/embed/?r=3`` will be changed to ``http://my.url/embed/3/r`` Any idea how to adjust this function to work with this scheme? As I dont think it would work with just small changes. Also the ``/r`` at the end might or might not be there.

Comment: If you can handle the structure of the url you could split the url by "/" and take the position where will be the parameter. A fancy way would go throught the url and take a specific segment.

Comment: Yeah thats true, just split it at / and at ? for the scheme parameter. Ill try to do something, I just hate jQuery and Regex even more, so its bit hard for me to edit/work with this.